# C# program selected Event in code

Tags: c#, wpf, listboxitem, selected

I am trying to program a `ListBoxItem` `Selected` event in code because I need dynamic `ListBoxItems`.  I am coding this in wpf, the following xaml works great:

```
<ListBoxItem Tag="cPage_Mod_Modules" Selected="ListBoxItem_Selected">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource sColor01}" Text="» " />
        <TextBlock Text="Moduler" VerticalAlignment="Center" Focusable="True" />
    </StackPanel>
</ListBoxItem>
```

The `Selected="ListBoxItem_Selected"` works fine.

But when I try to create the `ListBoxItem` in code, it doesn't work.  Here is my code:

```
IList<ListBoxItem> lbi = new List<ListBoxItem>();
ListBoxItem itemBox = new ListBoxItem();
itemBox.Tag = "cPage_Assignment_Overview";
itemBox.Selected += new EventHandler(ListBoxItem_Selected(this, null));
lbTask.Items.Add(itemBox);
```

I just want to route to the event `ListBoxItem_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)` when somebody is selecting an item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean how to wire up the event ? This should do it (assuming the function signature is compatible with the event handler signature ).

```
itemBox.Selected += ListBoxItem_Selected;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
itemBox.Selected += new EventHandler(ListBoxItem_Selected(this, null));
```

to

```
itemBox.Selected += ListBoxItem_Selected;
```

I am assuming your ListBoxItem_Selected is declared like this

```
 public void ListBoxItem_Selected(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
 {

 }
```